# PEPPER (SoftBank Robotics): ALSpeechRecognition Engine issue - How to restart it when it doesnìt work?

Tags: robotics, pepper

During my test on [Pepper](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/home_pepper.html), I found some difficulties in realizing continuative collaborative dialog.

In particular, after about 10 minutes, it seems that the [ALSpeechRecognition](https://www.arabicrobotics.com/Aldebaran/aldeb-doc-2.5.7.1/naoqi/audio/alspeechrecognition-api.html#ALSpeechRecognitionProxy::removeAllContext) engine stops working.

In other words, Pepper dialog panel remains empty and/or the robot does not understand my words, even if the structure worked some minute before.

I tried to stop and restart it (i.e., the engine) via SSH terminal, by using:

```
qicli call ALSpeechRecognition.pause 1
qicli call ALSpeechRecognition.pause 0
```

It should restart the engine according to the guidelines shown [here](https://www.arabicrobotics.com/Aldebaran/aldeb-doc-2.5.7.1/naoqi/audio/alspeechrecognition-api.html#ALSpeechRecognitionProxy::pause__bCR), but it does not work.

Thank you so much guys.

Sincerely,

Giovanni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [tutorial](https://www.arabicrobotics.com/Aldebaran/aldeb-doc-2.5.7.1/naoqi/audio/alspeechrecognition-tuto.html#alspeechrecognition-tuto), starting and stopping the speech recognition engine is done by subscribing/unsubscribing it.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to do this is unsubscribing and subscribing back to it. For me it also worked changing the speech reco language and chaging it back to the one you had previously.

Answer (score 0):

Luis is right and to do so just create a function as below given and call it if **ActiveListenning** event comes false from **ALSpeechRecognition** module. **Note**: Use **ALMemory** module to get data from ALSpeechRecogntion.

```
asr_service = ALProxy("ALSpeechRecognition",ip,port)
memory = ALProxy("ALMemory",ip,port)
def reset():
    asr_service.unsubscribe("ASR_Engine")
    asr_service.subscribe("ASR_Engine")

ALS = memory.getData("ALSpeechRecognition/ActiveListening")
if ALS==False:
    reset()
```